# How loop through the rows for unique users and record the number of matches in another SQL table?

Tags: mysql, loops, mariadb

I recently started to study SQL and I'm trying to solve the problem:
I have a voting table `db.votes`, it records the nickname, time and type. Like an event log. It now has 500,000 lines.

I need to record the total number of matches for each user (his total number of votes) in another `db.users` table in the `total_votes` column.

I can get the total votes for a user manually, like:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM voters WHERE username="john";
```

Also I can write down the received value in other table.

```sql
UPDATE users SET total_votes = 20 WHERE username="john";
```

But how to do it automatically with a loop?

I tried to google similar methods and found several options with SQL-T, but I'm not sure if this will suit me.

Comment: You probably dont have SQL and MYSQL and if you are new to both you probably have MySQL so the extra tag can likely be removed.

Comment: While you can do this as shown in the replies, you should ask yourself why you are saving a value that you can calculate easily on demand. Sometimes it makes sense but in your case I doubt.

Comment: @CetinBasoz, yes you are right. I wanted to get all unique nicknames and record the total for each nickname in another table. Perhaps I misunderstood the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in a number of ways. One of them looks like this:

```
with v (voter_id, vote_count) as
(
  select voter_id, count(*)
      from votes
      group by voter_id
)
 update users
  inner join v on v.voter_id = users.id
  set total_votes = v.vote_count;
```

Here is a [DBFiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/QjUoKD8O)

EDIT: I am not a MariaDb user and looks like MariaDb does not support CTE for updates. You can check its documentation to be sure. Anyway, then a subquery works:

```
 update users 
   inner join 
   (
      select voter_id, count(*) as vote_count
      from votes
      group by voter_id
   ) v on v.voter_id = users.id
  set users.total_votes = v.vote_count;
```

Here is [DBFiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/_g848nE9) for MariaDb 10.9.

Comment: I tried your code, it's what I need, thanks. Could you change it under MariaDB 10.10? Or point out the differences and I'll try to do it myself.

Comment: Wish you told it from the start, upir question was tagged mySQL and now both mySQL and MariaDb. I am editing my reply for Mariadb.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a correlated sub query for that, that would also work with multiple user

```
CREATE tABLe users(username varchar(10), total_votes int)
```

```
CREATE TABLE voters(username varchar(10))
```

```
UPDATE users 
  SET total_votes = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM voters WHERE username = users.username) 
  WHERE username="john";
```

> ```
> Rows matched: 0  Changed: 0  Warnings: 0
> ```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/RD-nf56R)

Comment: Would you not leave out the WHERE username="john" part so that it doesn't only do this to the john users?  I suspect you were just mimicking what OP was using but I believe your answer might need to not have a where statement?

Comment: because he wanted only john but when you change my query to `IN ('john','mary', 'waldi')` it would still give you a correct answer, try it

Comment: Oh you have to iterate over every name that exists?  Why not do that with a concatenation statement to allow dynamic column names, populated by using the Information Scheme for that table?  That way it could loop through all them.

Comment: that here is much faster